# Skipping certain iterations of a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm currently writing a for loop to go through a 2D with 38 elements. However, some of those elements are null and I want the for loop to simply skip over them (because in the puzzle I'm solving they have no moves associated with them). A quick search revealed that I can skip an iteration with a simple `continue` statement in an `if` statement at the beginning of the `for` loop. However, I want to skip multiple iterations, and the if statement I wrote isn't working:

```
for (int i = 0; i < triplets.length; i++) {
    if (i == 18 || 19 || 25 || 26 || 28 || 29 || 31 || 32) {
        continue;
    }
```

Is there an alternative to making 8 individual `if` statements or am I stuck with that?

Comment: You can't logically chain a condition like that, the `||` operator requires that you hand it a boolean on each side, e.g `i == 18 || i == 19 || ...`

Comment: You said the elements are null, so why can't you test for the element being null rather than attempting to specify the specific moves to be skipped? As to other alternatives, you can do `if (i == 18 || i == 19 ...)`. I would load into a List and check for presence in the list.  As I see @Cootri did below as I was typing...

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted for asking a simple question, but hey, that's the pedantic Overflow community for you. It seems it was a simple syntax error. Thank you for your help @azurefrog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not giving the condition properly. It should be something like this:

```
if (i == 18 || i == 19 || i == 25 || i == 26 || i == 28 || i == 29 || i == 31 || i == 32) {
    continue;
}
```

Alternatively, I would suggest you to do something like this instead:

1. Create a `HashSet` and put the values to be compared in it.
2. Check if `HashSet` contains `i` and if yes then continue the loop.

   ```
   Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
   set.add(18);
   set.add(19);
   set.add(25);
   set.add(26);
   set.add(28);
   set.add(29);
   set.add(31);
   set.add(32);

   if(set.contains(i)) {
       continue;
   }
   ```

Comment: @fge Just realized it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an alternative to making 8 individual if statements or am I stuck with that?

you can create excluding `List` and execute your code when current triplet doesn't exist in it (code is more concise without `continue` calls).

```
List<Integer> exclude = Arrays.asList(18, 19, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32);
for (int i = 0; i < triplets.length; i++) {
    if (!exclude.contains(i)) {
        ....//your code
    }
}
```

If the exclude list is big then it is a good idea to replace `ArrayList` with `HashSet`, which has *O(1)* search complexity instead of *O(N)* (but consumes about [5.5 times more memory](https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer/blob/master/ElementCostInDataStructures.txt) for each element)

Comment: Why do you have a `!` at the beginning?

Comment: @user7 Because you want to execute the block whenever the index is NOT in the exclude list.

Comment: Ok. But earlier you had `continue` inside your if